# Integrate alert of tradingview in my chart

Tags: angular

The requirement is that an alert needs to be created for my chart taken by trading view chart widget. https://www.tradingview.com/widget/advanced-chart/

However, it is showing the clock icon at the top but when I click on it, it shows

**This feature is available only on trading view.**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwhcP.png

So, any idea on how to integrate alert for my chart in angular 4?

Comment: tradingView is giving you the free embeddable chart... if it provides you all the options for free, how would they attract visitors, earn ?

Comment: I have already been a premium member of trading view, still it is showing me the message where I have integrated.